# How to hide comments from indexing?

Tags: 7, search, comments

I am using Drupal 7. I do not want comments to index in search module. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that I'd strongly recommend to go for Search API with maybe the db engine for these kind of customizations in case you don't have access to a Solr server.

Comments get indexed with their nodes through the invocation of [hook_node_update_index](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_update_index/7) I believe, in comment_node_update_index, so if you stop that hook from happening, comments won't ever index, with all the consequences, you could achieve this with [hook_module_implements_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_module_implements_alter/7).

Check out how migrate module does this to avoid some potentially harmful hooks to run on the migration:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_module_implements_alter().
 */
function migrate_module_implements_alter(&$implementation, $hook) {
  // Ensure that the Migration class exists, as different bootstrap phases may
  // not have included migration.inc yet.
  if (class_exists('Migration') && $migration = Migration::currentMigration()) {
    $disable_hooks = $migration->getDisableHooks();
    if (isset($disable_hooks[$hook])) {
      foreach ($disable_hooks[$hook] as $module) {
        unset($implementation[$module]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Another option you have is to just index the content and modify the search index/ search results to not display any trace of the comment, but I'm guessing what you're looking for is that the result is just not there.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to create a custom search page using [Views](https://drupal.org/project/views) and [Search API](https://drupal.org/project/search_api). With Search API you can select precisely what you want to get indexed.

Comment: ,I have used drupal core search throught the application.So,I need a solution using drupal core search